# How to connect to a FTP server over TLS (explicit) and upload a file to it [C#]

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpes

How would you go about connecting to an FTP server using the FTPES protocol and then upload a file?

I found this online:

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
 {
 client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
 client.UploadFile("ftp://ftpserver.com/target.zip", WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, localFilePath);
 }
```

... but it only works with normal ftp.

I had no luck searching for a method that works with ftpes.